# FFMPEG: How to add two more audio streams?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, youtube, stream

This is my already working stream:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://stream1video -i rtsp://stream2audio -c:v copy -map 1:v -map 2:a -preset veryfast -pix_fmt + -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/....
```

Now I would like to add two more audio files in the background in a loop.

something like this:
`-i /1.aac -i /2.aac`

So it should be something like:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://stream1video -i rtsp://stream2audio -stream_loop 1 -i /1.aac -stream_loop 1 -i 2.aac -c:v copy -map 1:v -map 2:a -map 3:a -map 4:a -preset veryfast -pix_fmt + -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/....
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to downmix all three audio streams into one add the [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://stream1video -i rtsp://stream2audio -re -stream_loop -1 -i 1.aac -re -stream_loop -1 -i 2.aac -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a][3:a]amix=inputs=3[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/
```